# Ubuntu 20.04 Sound issue

Tags: dual-boot, sound, mbr

Hy, there!!!
So, my problem is that the sound does not work correctly, actually it is something like an 8 bit sound from that old tetris console, and there is kinda echo. I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15ARE05, with Ryzen 5 4500U, 8GB ram, 512 SSD. Also i have a dual-boot on it: Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04.
After i installed Ubuntu (I've installed it on a single partition, without swap), it worked fine, but after like 2 days something happened to the sound and it does not work correctly. I should remark that previously on this Laptop were installed Manjaro KDE and it worked very fine.
May be this problem is because of the MBR partition structure(or how it's called), or because of the driver, idk.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found it in arch wiki
"Laggy sound

This issue is due to incorrect buffer sizes. First verify that the variables `default-fragment`s and `default-fragment-size-msec are not being set to non default values in the file /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. If the issue is still present, try setting them to the following values:

`/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`

`default-fragments = 5`

`default-fragment-size-msec = 2"`

this resolved my issue.